# absolute continuity and translation -invariant of $\mu$ measure

Tags: measure-theory

if I have a measure $\mu$ on $(a,b]$ such that $\mu(a,b]=F(b)-F(a)$ where  $F$ is non-decreasing, continuous function from the right, I know that if $F$ is not absolutely continuous, then $μ(A) > 0$ for some set $A$ of Lebesgue measure $0$. How can I prove that almost all translates of $A$ must have $μ$-measure $0$ ?
I'd like to prove that $\lambda(A)=0$ implies $\mu(A+x)=0$ for $x$ outside a set of Lebesgue measure zero. $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and is invariant under translation and reflection through $0$)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your definition of $\mu$, it is easy to see that $\mu$ is sigma-finite, so that we can apply Fubini's theorem.

Note that $\lambda(-A) = 0$ and hence
$$
\int \lambda(-A + x) \, d\mu (x)= \int \lambda(-A) \, d\mu = 0.
$$
But we also have
\begin{align*}
0=\int \lambda(-A + x) \, d\mu (x) &= \int \int 1_{-A+x} (y) \, d\lambda(y) \, d\mu(x) \\
&= \int \int 1_{-A+x}(y)\,d \mu(x) \, d\lambda(y) \\
&= \int \int 1_{A+y}(x) \, d\mu(x) \, d\lambda(y) \\
&= \int \mu(A + x) \, d \lambda(y).
\end{align*}
Since the integrand is nonnegative, it must vanish a.e., so that we get $\mu(A+x) = 0$ for $\lambda$-almost all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you @PhoemueX This is  exactly what I was looking for,  
Regards,